# Exchange testInstrumentationRunner with a runner derived from class not available at compile time

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, bytecode-manipulation, instrumented-test

I want to use a custom `testInstrumentationRunner` for overriding the `newInstance` method in order to use a custom application:

```
class UiTestJUnitRunner : AllureAndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader, className: String, context: Context): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

where that application is actually required to make the test execution work (since it skips some GDPR dialogs etc. at the startup):

```
class TestApplication : CoreApplication() {

    override fun initDebugInfo(): DebugInfo {

        return DebugInfo.builder()
            .disableSomeDialogs...()
            .build()
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to derive my `TestJUnitRunner` from `AllureAndroidJUnitRunner`. Unfortunately that `AllureAndroidJUnitRunner` is not available at compile time since it is a transitive dependency of another library I'm using (Kaspresso).

During execution of the tests the class is available on the classpath and can be instantiated by the test framework. So, I can actually get an instance using reflection at runtime.

I've tried several approaches like including the transitive dependency explictly (which results in a duplication and instances are created which don't know of each other), reflection combined with byte code manipulation (but didn't get it running properly), as well as creating a custom runner redirecting all package-private, protected and public methods to an instance of the required `testInstrumentationRunner` I've created by reflection (which also didn't succeed).

I'd be happy, if anyone has experience in this and can assist!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by NOT requiring to derive from `AllureAndroidJUnitRunner`. Instead I added a separate manifest in the `debug` folder overriding `application:name` to the `TestApplication`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="de.xyz...">

    <application
        tools:replace="android:name"
        android:name=".TestApplication"/>
</manifest>
```

It is required to put it into the `debug` folder since manifest merging will not take anything from `androidTest`.